# Column not lining up

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to achieve a column-style for converting celcius to fahrenheit.

My question: When I run it, the numbers are lining up nicely. However the c and f are aligned left and are not above the numbers. Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
def convert(celc):
    fahr = celc * 1.8 + 32
    return fahr

def table():
    format_str = '{0:10} {1:10}'
    c = 'c'
    f = 'f'
    cfhead = format_str.format(c, f)
    print(cfhead)
    for graden in range(-40,30,10):
        result = format_str.format(convert(graden), graden)
        print(result)

table()
```

Comment: I think because `c` and `f` are characters and others are numbers like float and integer and if you do `result = format_str.format(str(convert(graden)),str(graden))` it will work

Comment: @KalpeshDusane: why not just set an explicit alignment? And in format strings, if you add `!s` after the placeholder name / number, the value is converted with `str` for you.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters Thanks , I didn't know about the alignment method and I try converting it to string and it works, But I learn something new, So thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `>` in your format to always align to the right:

```
format_str = '{0:>10} {1:>10}'
```

The default is for strings to be left-aligned, numbers to be right-aligned.

From the [*Format Specification Mini-Language* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

> `'<'`
>   Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space (this is the default for most objects).
>
> `'>'`
>   Forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space (this is the default for numbers).

With an explicit alignment formatter you get your desired output:

```
>>> table()
         c          f
     -40.0        -40
     -22.0        -30
      -4.0        -20
      14.0        -10
      32.0          0
      50.0         10
      68.0         20
```